# Velostrata migration from AWS to GCP failed: [Cloud instance boot failed]

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-anthos, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I am running a migration of a simple WordPress site from AWS to GCP using velostrata.

I have set up the VPN between the two VPCs and successfully configured velostrata source and target clouds.

The migration process seem to go well for a while. I can see the instance created in the GCP console, but after a while it disappears.

When I look at the velostrata logs, the error is:

```sh
Finished job: RunInCloud on VM: i-0bc57fc47e893fac0, result: Failed, reason: [Cloud instance boot failed] (Instance boot was unsuccessful)
2019-06-20 15:00:34 DEBUG   VmWorkerImpl    
Exception:
com.velostrata.management.automation.exceptions.FailFlowException: [Cloud instance boot failed] (Instance boot was unsuccessful)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.flows.FlowBase.isDone(FlowBase.java:74)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.flows.RunInCloud.isDone(RunInCloud.java:113)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.monitor(VmWorkerImpl.java:126)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.runFlow(VmWorkerImpl.java:88)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.safeRunFlow(VmWorkerImpl.java:74)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.VmWorkerImpl.iterate(VmWorkerImpl.java:69)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.GroupWorkerImpl.lambda$run$3(GroupWorkerImpl.java:70)
   at com.velostrata.automation.infra.utils.Wait.till(Wait.java:40)
   at com.velostrata.automation.infra.utils.Wait.till(Wait.java:87)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.GroupWorkerImpl.run(GroupWorkerImpl.java:57)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.runGroup(JobsRunnerImpl.java:88)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.runPartOfJob(JobsRunnerImpl.java:80)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.run(JobsRunnerImpl.java:72)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.JobsRunnerImpl.start(JobsRunnerImpl.java:48)
   at com.velostrata.management.automation.components.RunsManagerImpl$RunFutureTask.lambda$new$0(RunsManagerImpl.java:246)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The source EC2 VM is just a simple Ubuntu instance running WordPress in docker and pointing to a RDS instance.

At this point I don't really know what should I do to get this working.
Any idea where should I start looking?

Thanks!

Comment: The instance did not boot up. You will need to contact their technical support to find the bug/issue with their software.

Comment: Weirdly enough, if I remove the `user data` attribute from the aws instance, the migration works and the new instance is created in GCP. I will raise this with the velostrata team as you suggest. Thanks @JohnHanley

Comment: @afcastano I have the same problem when I'm trying to migrate a VM. I don't know if there is some configurations boot in a specific disk. Did you get to migrate?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the following error is seen

```
Finished job: RunInCloud on VM: whateverVM, result: Failed, reason: [Cloud instance boot failed\](Instance boot was unsuccessful)
```

You may also perform the following troubleshooting steps

Check the instance serial console log for multiple timeout like:

```
[132.044894] dracut-initqueue[383]: calling: settle
[132.553566] dracut-initqueue[383]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
```

Run the following command, it must returns only ONE kernel (not multiple, neither an empty line):

> sudo grubby --default-kernel

Run the following command, all packages must be returned:

> sudo rpm -q iscsi-initiator-utils-iscsiuio iscsi-initiator-utils
>   device-mapper-multipath-libs device-mapper-multipath velostrata-prep

Run the following command, you expect a velostrata, multipath, iscsi module present for dracut, not a list of files:

> sudo lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-`uname -r`.img | egrep
>   "(velostrata|multipath|iscsi)" | head -3

Possible Resolution:

1.Uninstall and reinstall the prep package, providing the full output for debug purpose

2.If state is already installed, try to rebuild the initrd for the current kernel

Possible root cause:

Offline preparation fails to install the MPIO feature that is needed for Running in cloud which fails the migration task.